# String Uninitialized string offset -PHP

Tags: php

When Im running the next code:

```
function RandomLink()
        {
        $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $string = "";
        for($x = 0; $x< 30; $x++)           
            {
              $string .= $characters[(mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)))]; // Random char
            }

        return "$string.php";
        }
```

I get an error which says: Uninitialized string offset .What it mean's and how can i fix it?
I just dont want programming like a robot,I want understands behind the error may someone explain me too?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Try replacing `strlen($characters)` with `strlen($characters) - 1`

Comment: Worked thanks ! It was because the string length was too long ?

Comment: Yeah. Since the index starts at 0, the last index in the string is actually 1 less than the length

Comment: It's because the string is 0-indexed to 35 and your mt_rand goes from 0 to 36.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `mt_rand` parameter `max` is *inclusive*.  So `strlen($characters)` should be `strlen($characters)-1` since there is no character at the index equivalent of the  length of the string.

```
$string .= $characters[(mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1))];
```

If your string was length of 2 like `"ab"` then  `mt_rand(0, 2)` would return values 0, 1, and 2, which is `a`, `b`, and JUST ONE TOO FAR.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the offset you provided to `mt_rand()` is beyond `$characters` length. Update the `strlen($characters) - 1`.

Also, you've recreated - [`str_shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php):

Consider refactoring to:

```
function RandomLink() {
  $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  $hash = str_shuffle($characters);
  return substr($hash, 0, 30) . '.php';
}
```